# How to compress BLOB image stored in browser using javascript or reactjs and upload to server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image-compression

**Task done by me**

1. Select image using file input`<input type="file" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple" />`
2. Create Object url using `url: URL.createObjectURL(file[0])`. e.g url = blob:http://0.0.0.0:5002/e468fb70-d597-4b17-bb3a-ec6272f2d7fe.
3. Display the image in web page using `<img src={ url } width="100px" height="100px" />`

**Now what I want to do is**,

1. Read and Compress image from 
   url=blob:http://0.0.0.0:5002/e468fb70-d597-4b17-bb3a-ec6272f2d7fe
2. Upload compressed image to server

This project is in reactjs. Your suggestion will be helpful to me.

Comment: Conver image in base64

Comment: Thank you @SaqibAhmed. First thing, I don't know how to convert?. And after that how to apply compression on it?

Answer (score 2):

1. Read blob as ArrayBuffer using FileReader, then draw it on canvas and then compress it and pull out the compressed BLOB.

[Source code](https://gist.github.com/imanubhardwaj/a6791c3f543ea205ea34d66679983ee5)

2. Blob can be sent to server like any other data in body, nothing special is required for that.

Comment: Is there any other possible to do without canvas?. Because I am having more files so more BLOB URLS.

Comment: In your code. Few variable is missing . like var fileinput = document.getElementById('fileinput');

var max_width = fileinput.getAttribute('data-maxwidth');
var max_height = fileinput.getAttribute('data-maxheight');.

Same solution as yours. You can find more at here . https://github.com/josefrichter/resize/blob/master/public/preprocess.js